# Make mysql case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, case-sensitive

I wrote

```
select * from mytable
```

In my ASP.net app on Windows it works fine. On Linux it complains I used `mytable` instead of `MyTable`. How do I set MySQL on Windows to be case sensitive or set Linux to be case insensitive when dealing with table names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [8.2.2. Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) in the mySQL manual.

Short version: Use the [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) system variable to achieve case insensitivity on Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting for this. See this link: http://www.parkroad.co.za/blog/2007/02/07/mysql-case-sensitivity-of-table-names-between-windows-and-linux-systems

Here's the important part:
...you can look for the setting: lower_case_table_names in your my.ini file, found in or around: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1, depending on which version you are running. If you don't find the setting, you can just add it to the end of the my.ini file, as I did, like so:

lower_case_table_names=0

Dan